# JAVA Spring Basic CRUD API Implementation throws error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am creating a basic CRUD application in JAVA using Spring. 
I have a mysql table with following configurations
**database name:** *"first_crud_api"*
**table name:** *tb1_employee*
I have 5 columns in Employee table as follows............................................

[The table description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSMnZ.png)

I am trying to retrieve all the data from the table at one go using api...

It is a maven project, I am running my Spring application using Tomcat in port 8080..
WHEN I HIT "http://localhost:8080/api/employee" I get the error stating that

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Dec 22 14:32:57 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee is not mapped [from Employee]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee is not mapped [from Employee]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee is not mapped [from Employee]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee is not mapped [from Employee]
```

Please help resolving the issue... I am stuck

The application class:.....

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan("com.sring.crud.*")
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCrudApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public EmployeeDAO employeeDAO(){
        return new EmployeeDAOImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public EmployeeService employeeService(){
        return new EmployeeServiceImpl();
    }


}
```

The Repository interface and its implementation as follows

```
package com.sring.crud.DAO;

import java.util.List;

import com.sring.crud.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeDAO {

    List<Employee> get();

    Employee get(int id);

    void save (Employee employee);

    void delete (int id);

}
```

Implementation of repository methods:

```
package com.sring.crud.DAO;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.sring.crud.model.Employee;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entitymanager;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public List<Employee> get() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session currentSession = entitymanager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query<Employee> query = currentSession.createQuery("from Employee",Employee.class);
        return query.getResultList();


    }

    @Override
    public Employee get(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Employee employee) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The Entity class as follows:

```
package com.sring.crud.model;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb1_employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;
    @Column(name="department")
    private String department;
    @Column(name="dob")
    private Date dob;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }


    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + ", department=" + department + ", dob="
                + dob + "]";
    }
}
```

Service Interface and its implementation as follows.........

```
package com.sring.crud.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.sring.crud.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeService {

    List<Employee> get();

    Employee get(int id);

    void save (Employee employee);

    void delete (int id);
}
```

Implementation....

```
package com.sring.crud.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.sring.crud.DAO.EmployeeDAO;
import com.sring.crud.model.Employee;

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<Employee> get() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return employeeDAO.get();
    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Employee get(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void save(Employee employee) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: which package is class `SpringCrudApplication` located?

Comment: Package name is "com.spring.crud.SpringCRUDApplication"

Comment: since all necessary beans are located inside the package of application class, you don't need to perform component scanning. have you tried running it without this annotation? `@ComponentScan("com.sring.crud.*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't follow the best practice to put the Application class in the root package.

So you have to add a lot of annotation to make your app work but you forget EntityScan.

```
@EntityScan("com.sring.crud.model")
```

Also I'm not sure if this is an error while copy pasting your code in the question but the annotatoin have to be on the class level not on the main method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.sring.crud.*")
@EntityScan("com.sring.crud.model")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringCrudApplication.class, args);
}
```

**But I would highly recommend to follow the best practice and put your Application class in the packge `com.sring` then you only need:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCrudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Please read the docs where about structuring your application code:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class

Also why do you create your own DAO? There is Spring Data JPA for that purpose:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jpa-and-spring-data

Comment: it is unknown where his application class is located, that's why I asked him about that under his question